# Expand the scope of the site

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

I've noticed there are a lot of useful questions that get locked down on this site because they don't fit the site's rules, and that's fair enough people make rules for good reasons.

But there are a lot of questions I come across that would be really useful if they were left up and open, and I was wondering if there was any way that we could open these questions up in some way, you know maybe tag particular questions with something to let people know they aren't part of what has been the conventional question answer style.

I don't know the best way to do it, but I always happen across really useful questions that I wish hadn't been closed off, and I assume there are many others who feel the same. It would be nice to keep it contained in this site. I know we could push these questions across to another forum, but I have this niggling feeling that they actually belong here with this community and we'd be richer if we could support them.

Maybe I'm wrong I am but a man alas! But that's what I'm feeling. Does anyone else feel the same or have opposing ideas? Anything is welcome :)

Comment: Could you please provide links to specific closed topics you personally feel could be useful? This discussion won't work to well "in general", since "in general" the current scope came to the point it is at.

Comment: Well that's the problem its difficult to 'happen' across them again. I'll put them up as I find them though. Here's one example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file

Comment: Please file an [edit] and add a list of examples. Thanks.

Comment: Will do, if anyone has any examples themselves that would be great as I only find them by chance as I'm working on things. I do agree with Rarst that the reasons for the site's rules are good, tried and tested. I just love the site so much and it works so well with the navigation that I'd rather see the questions that fall outside this site's scope go into a site as good and easy to use as this one. I'm not saying it should  and I don't have the time to develop something like that myself. I thought I'd mention it and see if anyone shared that view, if not no worries the site is great as it is

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's start with that one:

## [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file)

First — note how it's very clearly **not a question**. :)

Second, since it *seems* in scope of WordPress development, let's hit the rules about why it might still not be a *good* fit.

> [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”

It pushes these buttons quite a bit, doesn't it?

This question clearly hit it off in social aspect. People like snippets, people like lists. Giant list of snippets is da bomb!

However, we are not a "108 Fantastic WordPress Snippets That Will Make You Rich and Lose Weight" kind of a site.

SE is looking to build knowledge collections that are **focused and high quality**.

This question exhibits both complete lack of focus and historically complete lack of proper quality maintenance. People like to throw those snippets in the pot (myself included in those days), but no one was willing (or obliged) to constantly maintain all that content.

It's a mess and as such it's rightfully (in my moderator opinion) closed mess.

Comment: Fair enough. It probably wasn't the best example but its nice to get your feedback. Yes I agree it does push those buttons! But that's my point I'm wondering if there is a place for questions like theses on this site. One thought was a second site where questions like these have a place to be move without damaging the focused and high quality nature of the site, which I do respect as it would be a mess if it became just a load of questions like this. Is there any way to keep the highly focused nature of the site as well as allowing a bit more freedom? I'll try and find some better examples :)

Comment: One site cannot be everything to everyone. Or we would only have one site on the Internet. :)

Comment: Haha well that would be an interesting site! I'd certainly use it. Well what do you think, we have all this interesting content that crops up on this site that people like, where does it belong?

Comment: I heard there is a software you can use to run something called a "blog".

Comment: Keep in mind too we're not alone on stack exchange in our treatment of such questions, and it's something that has been discussed amongst moderators from different stacks

Comment: Smart arse! Your approach is probably right, like I said I'm sure there's good reasons for the site rules. I just see a gap where this great content falls off the map. Is there a specific website your site recommends for migrating questions that don't fit the rules here?

Comment: I think Google+ communities on WordPress are recommended pretty often lately.

Comment: Oh ok cool thanks